# How to retrieve global varibles configured on the request url in the pre-request script

Tags: javascript, api, rest, postman

I am preparing a postman sample that uses some global variables in the url parameters.

[image]

The valibles {{api-url}} and {{public-address}} are defined under Globals.

[image]

I also have a script in Pre-request Script where it tries to retrieve the request url.

```js
var url = pm.request.url
console.log("URL=" + url)
```

However when I run this I do not get the url with the global variables filled in. Instead I get the below;

[image]

For the request itself I get the varibales filled in , I had to mask them due to privacy reasons.

I believe at the time of the Pre-reuest script the request url may not have filled with global variables? If so how can I get these valies in the url?

I definitely can re construct the URL in the Pre-request script itsef, but then that would duplicate things ...

Comment: What about `pm.globals.get('public-address');` ? Did you try it to get value from global scope?

Comment: It actually not bout getting the individual values. Its about getting  multiple values replaced in a entity like `pm.request.url` or `pm.request.body.raw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the actual request is resolving those values in the UI. If you're just needing to resolve the same in the log output, it would be like this:

```js
let url = pm.request.url
console.log("URL=" + pm.variables.replaceIn(url))
```

As the log statement is just a string value of the UI, the variables are displayed as they are in the request URL. You would need to use `replaceIn()` to substitute those for the resolved values.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#the-pm-object

Comment: Thanks Danny, That waorked!!